# how to assign a specific word according to number in admin grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I want to add the wording according to a number in the admin grid column.

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
$this->addColumn(
        'return_type',
        array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('requestreturn')->__('Return Type'),
            'index'  => 'return_type',
        )
    );
}
```

Here i am getting numbers i want to check the number in if and add the text to the column.

```
if(type="1"){
    $type = "New";
}elseif(type="2"){
    $type = "Old";
}
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can us `renderer` feature for admin grid,

```
$this->addColumn(
        'return_type',
        array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('requestreturn')->__('Return Type'),
            'index'  => 'return_type',
            'renderer'  => 'VENDOR_MODULENAME_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_ChangeReturnType'
        )
    );
```

Now create a new file `ChangeReturnType` as per the path define above,

```
<?php          
class VENDOR_MODULENAME_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_ChangeReturnType extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract    
{            
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $type = $row->getData('return_type');
        if(type="1"){
            $type = "New";
        }elseif(type="2"){
            $type = "Old";
        }
        return $type;
    }
}
```